# Why i cant multiply 0-9 numbers? using vb aND ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, math, double

Why i cant multiply 2-9 numbers ? for example the actual quantity is = 2.368 then i try to put 25 and its working ... when i try to put 9 up to 2  it does not multiply.. sometimes it multiply sometimes it dont ,,

```
<input type="text" runat="server" value="" id="requestQuantity" />
<input id="requestCost" runat="server" readonly="true"  value=""  />
 <input  id="ActualQuantity"  runat="server"  readonly="true" />
<asp:Label ID="Totalcost" runat="server" BackColor="White"></asp:Label>

    Dim x As Double
    If ActualQuantity.Value >= requestQuantity.Value Then
       x = requestCost.Value * requestQuantity.Value
        Totalcost.Text = x
    Else
        Dim message As String = "You must not put Greater Value than Available Quantity."
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
        sb.Append("alert('")
        sb.Append(message)
        sb.Append("')};")
        sb.Append("</script>")
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
    End If
```

Comment: I see requestCost is readonly and has a value of a blank string. Is it always blank? If so, why multiply by a blank string? Is there some other code that is setting requestCost or actualQuantity?

Comment: the value come from my database .. 2.379 sometimes 2548.4...its the unit cost actually

Comment: sometimes it multyply Actual quantity=500 then i put 50 ... it worked .. when the actual quantity is 10 then i put 5 its not working ... it wont calculate ... im confused ... the Actual quantity must be greater than Requestquantity .. and im doing it right .. but sometimes its not working

Comment: I think Mark Hurd is onto your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`Option Strict On` would show you the problem here, but your issue is that the `.Value` properties are `String` and so

- `"2.368" >= "2"` is `True`
- `"2.368" >= "25"` is `False`
- `"2.368" >= "3"` is `False`
- `"2.368" >= "9"` is `False`

and

```
If CDbl(ActualQuantity.Value) >= CDbl(requestQuantity.Value) Then
```

will avoid the issue.

Hmmm... actually for this example, I think `>=` may produce the right results, but it fails for `"20.368"`.

Answer (score 0):

already solve the problem..i just need to put double in request quantity .. thank you for ur help

```
    Dim x As Double

    If (reqAQ.Value) >= Convert.ToDouble(requestQuantity.Value) Then
        x = Convert.ToDouble(requestCost.Value) * Convert.ToDouble(requestQuantity.Value)
        Totalcost.Text = x
```